# ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) in Julia

Tags: sql, com, ado, julia

I normally use instances of ADO objects to connect to databases (MSSQL/ Oracle). Is that something that I can do in Julia?

Answer (score 1):

You'd typically connect to a database over ODBC.

You can use the [ODBC low level library](https://github.com/quinnj/ODBC.jl) to make this a bit easier.