# How can I Call Motor-Cad server from Julia (in Matlab would be actxserver)

Tags: com, julia

I have read a couple of people comming to Julia from other languages like Python and Matlab.
I come from Matlab, I am really new to Julia and one of the biggest hurdles I am finding is how to call a COM-server like you would do for Excel or Motor-Cad or Siemens MagNet or Ansys Maxwell etc... from Julia.
If I was doing it in matlab I would work with server=acxserver('name of the server'), and after that I get the COM and I would be able to poke it for methods, properties etc...

When it comes to database and excel I have seen that there are libraries to go around the issue, but does anuyone know how to do something similar to the acxserver? I don't think a standard option like this:
[Julia Excel Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361415/julia-excel-object/62362871#62362871)
or this
[ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854629/activex-data-objects-ado-in-julia)
would solve my issue.

Link to what I would use in Matlab:
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-com-objects-in-matlab.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav
Link to the forum of motorcad talking about the same:
https://forum.ansys.com/forums/topic/motorcad-scripting/

Thansk for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a full answer to your question but I'll venture a guess and say this is a pretty niche application in the Julia community. You might be better served by posting on the Julia Discourse, where most of the community hangs out.

Currently the best option to search for Julia packages is juliahub.com, going there I found this potentially related package:

https://github.com/aptmcl/KhepriAutoCAD.jl

It's lacking documentation and doesn't seem to be well maintained, but maybe contacting the author on GitHub gets you somewhere.

Comment: Hi @Nils. First, thanks for your answer. I will do as you suggest and ask the question in julia discourse. I assume it is a niche application as I have not found the solution straight away. I will check that package! Thanks again for the advice.